# How can i use chartjs-chart-financial in a vue3 project?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, chart.js, vuejs3

I've had a problem for several days. I can't use chartjs-chart-financial in my vu3 project.
I keep getting this error: "candlestick" is not a registered controller.

link to package : https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-chart-financial

my code :

```
<template>
    <div style="width: 1000px">
      <canvas ref="chart" id="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import "chartjs-chart-financial/dist/chartjs-chart-financial";
  import Chart from "chart.js/auto";

  export default {
    mounted() {
      const ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
      const data = {
        datasets: [
          {
            type: "candlestick", 
            data: [
              { t: new Date("2023-01-01"), o: 100, h: 120, l: 90, c: 110 },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };
      const options = {
      };
      const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "candlestick",
        data: data,
        options: options,
      });
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b60m3.png)

Can anyone helps me ?

I've tried to run chartjs-chart-financial on vue2 and it works, but it's not possible to change my project to vue2. Maybe there's a way to wrap the package under vue in my vue3 project? I'm willing to consider all answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.